# Install lib files in red-hat from file

Tags: redhat, package-management, library

One question about installing libs.

I have a RH 6.4, and I need some libs to be updated in the SO. I've been provided with the actual version, those are in file format  libicudata.so.36.0 libicui18n.so.36.0  libicuuc.so.36.0

Is there a way to install them by command and update dependencies? I've made a locate of those librarys, and previous versions exists on multipla places of the machine, not as simbolic links. That's why I want to be sure instead of just replacing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trying, I've got a solution.

These external libraries needs to be copied on **/usr/lib**

Once they have been copied, you have to reload the libraries to make the new ones available

```
ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib
```